# which files are necessary for bootstrap dropdown to work?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, dropdown, nuxt.js

I am avoiding including the entire bootstrap source code in my app. All I need at this point is the bootstrap dropdown classes. I am trying to make a simple dropdown that looks like this...

```
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">display dropdown</a>
    <ul
      class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-arrow dropdown-scrollable dropdown-content"
    >
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 1</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I copied dropdown.scss from the tabler.io library.

This is all it contains...

```
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  color: orange;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  box-shadow: $dropdown-box-shadow;
  min-width: 12rem;
}

.dropdown-item {
  color: $text-muted-dark;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.dropdown-menu-arrow {
  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    left: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid $border-color;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    content: "";
  }

  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    content: "";
  }

  &.dropdown-menu-right {
    &:before,
    &:after {
      left: auto;
      right: 12px;
    }
  }
}

.dropdown-toggle {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:after {
    vertical-align: 0.155em;
  }

  &:empty:after {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.dropdown-icon {
  color: $text-muted;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  width: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: -1px;
}
```

I know that my code is referencing this stylesheet because the font color is orange and the stylesheet's first rule includes `color: orange`.

[image]

I also know that my code detects the user clicking on the text because I tested by adding @click.prevent="doSomething()" where doSomething() simply console logged a message.The message did indeed print out in the Chrome dev tools console.

However, when I click on the words `display dropdown`, the dropdown menu does not open.

I understand there are javascript files I may need. Which files are those and how can I make sure my code uses this file? This is a Vuejs app using Nuxt.

Comment: Try to use popper.js. Bootstrap 4 required popper.js to work dropdown.  `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js`  [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h)

Comment: I'm not using all of bootstrap 4. I want to only use the necessary files. Will I need other files or just popper.min.js?

Comment: If you want drop-down to work using jquery and bootstrap, Than you need to use bootstrap 4(CSS and js ) and popper.js